# Using SED to replace a domain name in a large number of HTML files

Tags: regex, replace, sed, find, escaping

Ok, I give up. I've been trying for a couple of hours to get sed to replace an incorrectly formatted domain name in several thousand html files but I cannot seem to get the escaping of the slashes (and possibly dot/colon) correct.

**Text to find:**
http://www.domain.com/http

**Replace with:**
http

What i have tried:

```
sed -i 's/http:\/\/www.domain.com\/http/http/'
sed -i 's/http\\:\\/\\/www\\.domain\\.com\\/http/http/'
sed -i 's/http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/http/http/'
sed -i 's=http://www.domain.com/http=http='
```

**UPDATE:**

As it transpires I was chasing chasing ghosts. A piece of javascript was adding the http://www.domain.com/ to the beginning of all my img tags! Unfortunately now I need to try and remove this from all pages. So instead of the above, i am now looking to:

**Replace this:**
http://www.domain.com/'+img[0]

**with this:**
'+img[0]

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
find . -name "*.html" -type f -exec sed -i 's|http://www\.domain\.com/\'+img\[0\]|\'+img\[0\]|g' {} \;
find . -name "*.html" -type f -exec sed -i 's|http://www\.domain\.com/\'+img[0]|\'+img[0]|g' {} \;
```

I appear to be stuck on the escaping of certain chars again. Only this time when i try to run one of the above commands it just takes me to a > prompt.

Comment: Any help regarding my update is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid alot of the escaping by using a different delimiter. The dot `.` is the only character of special meaning that needs to be escaped, everything else you can match literally. Also use the global modifier with your pattern.

```
sed -i 's|http://www\.domain\.com/http|http|g'
```

**Edit** — You can use the following to replace the other part.

```
sed -i "s|http://www\.domain\.com/\('[+]img\[0\]\)|\1|g"
```

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. Testing this out as I type

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. It appears I was chasing ghosts with my first request as JS was adding the domain part that I was trying to remove. I've updated my original question.

Comment: @jamesnapier I've updated according to your question.